# Check if List is of one type or other

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have `List<Zones>` and `List<Locations>` and i am passing it to a generic function...

```
public String checkListType(List<?> checkList){
    // Now here I want to check if list is of type locations than
        return "locations"
    else {
        return "Zones";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. A List is a List. At runtime, the generic type has been erased. Encapsulate the lists in two different classes, like ZoneList and LocationList. The only thing you could do is get the first element of the list and check its type, but it would only work if there is at least one element (and it's really ugly).

Comment: @nkr I don't think you can, the two overloaded methods would have the same erasure.

Comment: JB Nizet is right. A possible workaround could be getting the first element and checking its type, but you will have to define a behavior for the empty list.

Comment: @A.R.S. You are right, this does not work. JB's comment is the way to go.

Comment: Ok guys i will go with overloaded method...overloaded idea was in my mind but i was trying to see if there is any possibility...Thanks all of you for your efforts.

Comment: @HaseebWali Overloading will not work as JB stated out.

Comment: @nkr overloading method is definately working....
"public String(List<Zones> zoneList){}" and make another overloaded method "public String(List<Locations> locList){}"

Comment: @HaseebWali I don't know which JDK you are using but when I try to compile such code I get this: `Generics.java:20: error: name clash: foobar(List<Integer>) and foobar(List<String>) have the same erasure`

Comment: @nkr Brother if you are more curious about it then give me your email i can mail you code which is working perfectly by using mehtod overloading...Because my class is big that's why i do't want to post it here..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  I'll answer it as asked, but if you provide more information about what you're trying to do, I may have a better answer for you.

Generics in Java are not available at runtime; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

You have a few options.  You could pass the class into the method.

```
public <T> String checkListType(Class<T> clazz, List<T> checklist) {
   if ("Locations".equals(clazz.getName()) {
   } else if (...) {
   }
}
```

You could also use reflection to identify the type of the first element.

```
public String checkListType(List<?> checkList) {
   if (!checkList.isEmpty()) {
       Class<?> itemClass = checkList.get(0).getClass();
       if ("Locations".rquals(clazz.getName()) {
          ...
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: First idea is quiet attracting and it worked(both options are availiable)..thankyou for your help.!!!!

Comment: If you know that you only need to differentiate `Zones` from `Locations` this solution works. But, if in future, `checkListType` has to differentiate types like `Zones<String>` and `Zones<Integer>` this solution will break.

Answer (score 0):

May this help.

```
public String checkListType(List<?> checkList){
    if( checkList == null || checkList.isEmpty() ) {
      return "UnKnown" ;
    }
    Object obj = checkList.get(0);
    if( obj instanceof Zones ) {
         return "Zones";
    } else if( obj instanceof Locations ) {
                 return "locations" ;
    }     
    else {
      return "Unknown";   
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know that you only need to differentiate `Zones` from `Locations` this solution works. But, if in future, `checkListType` has to differentiate types like `Zones<String>` and `Zones<Integer>` this solution will break.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the signature of the method to add a new parameter, you can use the [Super Type Token pattern](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) to identify the type parameter at runtime. Both super type tokesn and `Class<T>` can differentiate `Locations` from `Zones`. However, super type tokens are more powerful because they can can differentiate `Set<Locations>` from `Set<Zones>` as well.

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides an implementation of [TypeToken](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html).

```
public <T> String checkListType(List<T> checkList, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
    if (typeToken.equals(TypeToken.of(Locations.class))) {
        return "Locations";
    } else {
        return "Zones";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics are implemented using type erasure so you cannot do so easily. If the lists are known to be non-empty, you could do something like

```
public String checkListType(List<?> checkList){
    Object first = checkList.get(0);
    if (first instanceof Locations) {
        return "locations"
    else {
        return "Zones";
    }
}
```

But this is A Very Bad Idea.

From Effective C++, by Scott Meyers :

> Anytime you find yourself writing code of the form "if the object is of type T1, then do something, but if it's of type T2, then do something else," slap yourself.

quoted from http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31

Comment: If you know that you only need to differentiate `Zones` from `Locations` this solution works. But, if in future, `checkListType` has to differentiate types like `Zones<String>` and `Zones<Integer>` this solution will break.

Comment: Totally agreed. That's why I strongly encouraged OP not to try to do this.